# Ruby how to access specific keys and their hashes

Tags: ruby, key

So I attempted to search this up on here, but didn't find anything. I just started attempting to learn ruby yesterday and trying to set up a guessing game where it will prompt only the "Country" then we will have to guess the correct answer for the "area" we want to visit for an example.

heres a sample code to help visualize what I am trying to do:

```
places =[
{
  Country: "Japan",
  Area: "Tokyo"
}, {
  Country: "Korea",
  Area: "Seoul"
}]

guess = places.each_value do |guessing|
  print guessing
end
```

I tried doing things that say I can grab values by doing `.each_value` however, it gave me an error.

So how would I do some form of iteration for every user input but with the actual specific country being prompt first, then checking for the area?

Comment: "it gave me an error" <-- it would be of benefit if you were to include in your question the error which it gave you.

Answer (score 1):

There is no method `each_value` for an array. As you have an array of hashes, you need to iterate over array with `each` and then do whatever you want with the hashes inside.

```
places =[
{
    Country: "Japan",
    Area: "Tokyo"
}, {
    Country: "Korea",
    Area: "Seol"
}]

guess = places.each do |hash|
  print hash
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
places.each { |hash|
  puts "Guess area for #{hash[:Country]}"
  guess = gets.chomp
  if hash[:Area] == guess
    puts 'correct'
  else
    puts 'incorrect'
  end
}
```

Or perhaps consider doing something like this:

```
places = { "Japan": "Tokyo", "Korea": "Seol" }

places.each { |country, area|
  puts "Guess area for #{country}"
  guess = gets.chomp
  puts area == guess ? 'correct' : 'incorrect'
}
```

Here we've restructured your data to use only a hash and then used the ternary operator for printing the correctness of the answer.